# Requisition method PUT angular

Tags: angular, typescript, put

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Noopj.png)I have the following problem, when I try to put to an api the server returns the error 405.
can you help me?
Below is the code so you can check if you see any error in my code that may be generating this error...
I believe there may be something wrong with the Component's Typescript.
I believe there may be something wrong with the Component's Typescript

```js
Service Typescript


  getUser(id: any): Observable<ResponseUse> {
    const _url = `${this.apiClient}/${id}`
    return this.http.get<ResponseUse>(_url);
  }

  updateUser(id: any, request: ResponseUpdate): Observable<ResponseUpdate> {
    const _url = `${this.apiClient}/${id}`
    return this.http.put<ResponseUpdate>(_url, request);
  }
```

```html
COMPONENT UPDATE 

<div class="backgroud">
  <h1>Update user</h1>
    <div class="label" *ngIf="request">
      <label>
        ID:
        <input placeholder="ID" [(ngModel)]="request.id" />
      </label>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="request.name" />
      </label>
      <label>
        Email:
        <input placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="request.email" />
      </label>
      <label>
        Telephone:
        <input placeholder="Telephone" [(ngModel)]="request.telephone" />
      </label>
    </div>
  
    <div class="btn">
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary"  (click)="update()">
      Update
      </button>
      <button mat-stroked-button routerLink="/">Cancel</button>
  
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  TYPESCRIPT COMPONENT 
  
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { RequestUpdate } from 'src/app/model/live.model';
import { apiService } from 'src/app/services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-client-update',
  templateUrl: './client-update.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client-update.component.css']
})
export class ClientUpdateComponent implements OnInit {

  id: any;
  request!: RequestUpdate;
  
  constructor(
    private clientService: apiService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.clientService.getUser(this.id).subscribe(res =>{
      this.request = {
        id: res.id,
        name: res.name,
        email: res.email,
        telephone: res.telephone
      }
    })
  }

  update(){
    this.clientService.updateUser(this.id, this.request).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(`${this.request}`)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: check your server side code if PUT is allowed there on the resource?

Comment: Yes, the PUT method is allowed, I'll attach a screenshot of the error on google below

Comment: I added a photo at the beginning of the text

Comment: Did you try to hit this URL using postman?

Answer (score 0):

a response code of 405 indicates that the method (PUT) is not allowed for the endpoint you are requesting.

Double check that a PUT method is accepted and that the url you are sending the request to is accurate (no typo's and such). Also worth checking the developer console on your browser to make sure the full endpoint is compiled correctly

[edit] 405 status code MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405

http status codes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: But I believe I'm making this error, when using the site https://resttesttest.com/ to perform a test in the PUT method, I got error 405 and the message content-length:0

Comment: I added a photo at the beginning of the text